# How does vault PostgreSQL plugin of database secret engine with PostgreSQL backend work?

Tags: postgresql, hashicorp-vault

I was thinking if I specified the backend and secret engine plugin to be connected to the same postgreSQL server, I can gain the dynamic secrets feature and store secrets in the same place encrypted at the same time. When I tried to apply it I got more confused as you get a token to access the database directly which implies no encryption is there with one being able to store secrets directly. I thought of combining "Encryption as a Service" from vault with database secret engine to achieve this but want to make sure that there is no other way.

Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL secret engine doens't store data, but generates dynamic credential to access the PostgreSQL server.

If you want to store encrypted data in the PostgreSQL server use it as storage backend, and use a K/V secret engine. Every data of Vault, included the secrets of the K/V engine, will be stored in the database (of course everything is crypted).

Remember that the secrets engine does not specify where data is stored, they are just a secret service of Vault. The storage backend is the location where data is stored

Comment: I added KV and did store stuff and red it again. However, when I browsed the database I couldn't find where the encrypted data lives. I wanted to see the data while being at rest. Is it possible to see the cipher-text that vault stores in the backend database?

Comment: Everything should be in the `vault_kv_store` table on the database, K/V paths are not obfuscated so you should easily identify your values. However, there is no reason about letting you watch encrypted stuff, only Vault should be able to manipulate it. Alternatively, you can use the Transit backend to encrypt data and manually save it in your database

Comment: That's is where I searched and found nothing about secrets I stored. I need to play the bad guy role where I gain access some how to the PostgreSQL DB, but then I expect secrets are encrypted but they are no where to be found (as cipher-text). 
To make my self clear, I am trying to see what is best solution to mitigate the risk of the DB being hacked by making sure that data are in cipher-text form.

Comment: Every data in the storage backend (including Vault configurations) is encrypted with a key derivated from the master key, that is created with the shares when Vault is unsealed. The only one who knows the encryption key is Vault, so basically the PostgreSQL storage backend is safe from external attack. Data is also encrypted when it transit between Vault and the storage backend. Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks gic186 I appreciate your help. 
I am aware of vault's concepts though :-). What I am aiming at is to see the cipher text (The result of the encryption) or an explanation why it doesn't show up. Like I understand something and practice is not matching what I've understood.

Comment: Well.. If you searched on the DB table and you founded nothing useful, maybe is a good thing. Because neither an attacker could locate the cyphertext :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173958/discussion-between-gic186-and-badr).